# How to find the occurance of a specific tag in a XML file using C with libxml2 library?

Tags: c, xml-parsing, libxml2

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<UnlimitRectCubes>
    <RectCubes>
        <depth>0</depth>
        <rectangle>
            <height>0</height>
            <width>0</width>
        </rectangle>
    </RectCubes>
    <RectCubes>
        <depth>1</depth>
        <rectangle>
            <height>11</height>
            <width>101</width>
        </rectangle>
    </RectCubes>
    <RectCubes>
        <depth>2</depth>
        <rectangle>
            <height>22</height>
            <width>202</width>
        </rectangle>
    </RectCubes>
</UnlimitRectCubes>
```

Note: I've  also included, .xml file

```
void print_element_names(xmlNode *a_node, char **findStr)
{
    xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;
    char *key = *findStr;
    cur_node = a_node;
    int len = 0;

while (cur_node)
{
 if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur_node->name, (const xmlChar *)key)))
    {
        len++; //len is int type
    }
  cur_node = cur_node->next;
}
  printf("%d", len);
   //int i = 0;
//xmlChar *array = (xmlChar *)calloc(1, sizeof(xmlChar));
for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next)
{
    if ((cur_node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE))
    {
        if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur_node->name, (const xmlChar *)key)))
        {
            //printf("%s", cur_node->children->content);
        }
    }
    print_element_names(cur_node->children, findStr);
}
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    xmlDoc *doc = NULL;           /* an xml document */
    xmlNode *root_element = NULL; /* a node in a xml tree */
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        return (1);
    }
    LIBXML_TEST_VERSION
    /*  parse the file and get the DOM */
    doc = xmlReadFile(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    if (doc == NULL)
    {
        printf("error could not parse");
        return;
    }
    /*Get the root element*/
    root_element = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
    char *myStr = "depth";
    print_element_names(root_element, &myStr);

    xmlFreeDoc(doc);

    /*
        *free the global variables that may have been allocated by the     parser
    */
    xmlCleanupParser();

    return 0;
}
```

Output: 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I need to find the frequency of occurrence of a particular tag in an .xml file, which here I have passed as a key (char*) to a function, and using xmlStrCmp() to validate the right tag.

The len is supposed to print integer value, but it seems to output this: Please refer output above. There is actually 3 occurrence of a particular tag, and output show has 3 1's.
I believe, I am not traversing the XML tree properly, what is the right way to do it? or is there any XML function available to achieve this?

Input: .xml file and a tag of interest passed as key
Expected Output: No. of occurence of a tag, in this case I should get 3.

```
for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next)
{
    if ((cur_node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE))
    {
        if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur_node->children->name, (const xmlChar *)key)))
        {
            //printf("%s\n", cur_node->children->content);
        }
         printf("%s", cur_node->name);   
 }
    
    len += print_element_names(cur_node->children, findStr);
}
printf("%d ", len);
```

Updated Output:
UnlimitRectCubes0 RectCubes0 depth0 2 0 rectangle0 height0 2 0 width0 2 0 10 0 11 0 RectCubes0 depth0 2 0 rectangle0 height0 2 0 width0 2 0 10 0 11 0 RectCubes0 depth0 2 0 rectangle0 height0 2 0 width0 2 0 10 0 11 0 17 3

Comment: @Gerhardh I have added more info with regard to code

Comment: @Gerhardh I have now added complete code and also the .xml file which I am using. the for-loop section was missing before

Comment: Now it makes sense and it is obvious why you do not get more than 1 ever. You only find 1 element per object. You call the function recursively for the children of a node. If you find the tag in one of these calls, there is no result propagated back to the caller and you will never count the tags found in children.

Comment: You don't seem to care about the structure of the XML a lot. Are you aware that you will count all tags with same name on any nesting level or within any enclosing object?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with xml structure, just referred basic of it in a  website, can you recommend any good resource explaining structure of xml. All tags with same name in any nesting level is what this code works on right.

Comment: I don't work with that stuff, but if you need to use more specific filtering, you would need to search for enclosing tags first and only then for the inner tags. Maybe just split that recursive function into 2 for each level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not propagate the number of found tags on one level up to the calling level.

I tried this code and got correct result:

```
/*
 * Compile with:
 * > gcc `xml2-config --cflags` -std=c99 -o test  test.c `xml2-config --libs`
 * */
 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>

int print_element_names(xmlNode *a_node, char **findStr)
{
    xmlNode *cur_node = a_node;
    char *key = *findStr;
    int len = 0;

    if (a_node == NULL)
        return 0;
    
    printf("a_node->name=%s\n", a_node->name);
    while (cur_node)
    {
        printf("cur_node->name=%s, type=%d\n", cur_node->name, cur_node->type);
        if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur_node->name, (const xmlChar *)key)))
        {
            len++; //len is int type
        }
        cur_node = cur_node->next;
    }
    printf("found=%d\n", len);

    for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next)
    {
        if ((cur_node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE))
        {
    
            printf("search children for cur_node->name=%s, type=%d\n", cur_node->name, cur_node->type);
            len += print_element_names(cur_node->children, findStr);
        }
    }
    printf("found total for a_node->name %s: %d\n", a_node->name, len);
    return len;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    xmlDoc *doc = NULL;           /* an xml document */
    xmlNode *root_element = NULL; /* a node in a xml tree */

    LIBXML_TEST_VERSION
    /*  parse the file and get the DOM */
    doc = xmlReadFile("test.xml", NULL, 0);
    if (doc == NULL)
    {
        printf("error could not parse");
        return 1;
    }
    /*Get the root element*/
    root_element = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
    char *myStr = "depth";
    print_element_names(root_element, &myStr);

    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
    xmlCleanupParser();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems to output this: 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 2 0 10 0 11 0 0 1
0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 2 0 10 0 11 0 0 2
0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 2 0 10 0 11 0 17 3  It doesn't ensure to increment len only for tag of interest isn't it? I have only added changes suggested by you (len +=  print_element_names() ) in the code which I have posted.

Comment: Please add prints of node names together with corresponding len to your program.

Comment: UnlimitRectCubestext0 RectCubestext0 depthtext0 2 text0 rectangletext0 heighttext0 2 text0 widthtext0 2 text0 10 text0 11 text0 RectCubestext0 depthtext0 2 text0 rectangletext0 heighttext0 2 text0 widthtext0 2 text0 10 text0 11 text0 RectCubestext0 depthtext0 2 text0 rectangletext0 heighttext0 2 text0 widthtext0 2 text0 10 text0 11 text0 17 3   I've added cur_node->name.

Comment: Where did you put the print? Where does the `text` come from? Maybe you need to filter on node type in some way. Please add updated code together with that output to your question. Just add new code, no need to remove the initial version.

Comment: to remove text, I have now added print for cur_node->name inside, node type condition check. Please refer updated code, have also put updated output. after filtering text.

Comment: I'm not sure how you added the changes into your program but I did not get same results. With a bit tweaking I now get correct result 3.

Comment: Hey, Gerhardh, I tried your code with those tweaks and now is working properly. Thank you! I've accepted the answer and able understand recursive calls properly now :)

Comment: Continuing, I want to dynamically store these tags in an array in that function and return a ptr to that array. Since it's a recursive func, how do I allocate memory to array?    If I pass the array as args, how would I assign values to array in the recursive calls

Comment: That is a different topic. Please post a new question with the code where you try to solve that issue.